Finding Static Conditions from Total conditions
I am trying to create a code which determines the static properties of a flow given the total (stagnation) conditions, plus an area and mass flow rate. Since the velocity and as an extension, the mach number are determined by the mass flow rate using STATIC conditions, the process becomes iterative until a solution is converged on to. Below is a snippet of my code. It takes in the flow properties from the object, Flow, and converts them from imperial to metric units. The code seems to work fine for cases where the flow is subsonic. When the flow is sonic, it seems to diverge. What is a possible solution for this?
function Flow = StaticFromTotal(Flow, Ac)
import TMATSC.*
global fs
set( fs, 'Y',Flow.CompVal_Can);

mdot = Flow.W*0.45359237;   %kg/s
To   = Flow.Tt*(5/9);       %K
Po   = Flow.Pt*6894.75729;  %Pa
gam  = Flow.gamt;           %-
Ac   = Ac*0.09290304;       %m^2

set(fs, 'T', To,'P',Po );
equilibrate(fs, 'TP');
MW = meanMolecularWeight(fs);
Rs = 8314/MW;

Kmach = (mdot/Ac)*(Rs/gam)^0.5;
Err = 1;
Mg = Kmach*(To^0.5/Po);
while abs(Err)>1e-5
    K = 1+0.5*(gam-1)*Mg^2;
    Ts = To*K^-1;
    Ps = Po*K^(-gam/(gam-1));
    Mgc = Kmach*(Ts^0.5/Ps);
    Err = Mgc-Mg;
    Mg = Mgc;
end
Flow = Flow.set_TsPsMN(Ts*9/5, Ps*0.00014504, Mg);
end

Here is a snippet of my variable outputs:
Err = 1
Mg = 0.8304
Ts = 1.0791e+03
Ps = 2.0385e+05
Mgc = 1.2119
Err = 0.3815
Ts = 973.7015
Ps = 1.3165e+05
Mgc = 1.7825
Err = 0.5706
Ts = 801.8916
Ps = 5.7656e+04
Mgc = 3.6936
Err = 1.9111
Ts = 385.3889
Ps = 2.5555e+03
Mgc = 57.7719
Err = 54.0784
Ts = 2.3220
Ps = 9.2384e-07
Mgc = 1.2404e+10
Err = 1.2404e+10
Ts = 5.0467e-17
Ps = 1.2536e-77
Mgc = 4.2616e+72
Err = 4.2616e+72
Ts = 4.2755e-142
Ps = 0
Mgc = Inf
Err = Inf
Ts = 0
Ps = 0
Mgc = NaN
Err = NaN

because you typically can't use the same equations for compressible and incompressible flow?

Hey @TigerGuy, I am using the isentropic relations to relate the mach number to static and total properties. I believe these should be applicable from subsonic and supersonic regimes

Could this be because the flow is choked for the given area?
